# What's the difference between "left_joins" and "includes" in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5, they have added the ActiveRecord query method `left_joins`.  What's the difference between `left_joins` and `includes`? I've always seen `includes` as a left join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`includes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) by default loads the association data in 2 queries just like [`preload`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/preload). 
But with additional [`references`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references) call it switches from using two separate queries to creating a single `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like [`left_joins`](http://docs.w3cub.com/rails~5.1/activerecord/querymethods/#method-i-left_outer_joins).

Refs:

[Preload, Eagerload, Includes and Joins](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html)

[Making sense of ActiveRecord joins, includes, preload, and eager_load](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/01/24/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where)

Comment: Includes will also defer to `.eager_load` and load the records in one query if you apply a where clause.

Comment: @max But you cant use eager loaded tables via `includes` in `where` clause by default. You need to specify them in `references` first

Comment: I''m not sure what you mean but you can do `Foo.includes(:bars).where(bars: { baz: 'woo' })`. The result is the same as if you used eager_load.

Comment: @max yeah but if you change your example to `Foo.includes(:bars).where("bars.baz = 'woo'")` it will throw an error. Check out `conditions` part in [`includes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) docs

Comment: @max But I didnt know that `hash` notation works without `references` call so thank you