# Why does database functions break rails query plan on includes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

A plain call works as intended. The resulting SQL uses **LEFT OUTER JOIN**s to link tables as desired.

```rb
> Subscription.includes(plan: { student: :person }).order('persons.name')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation ... >
```

If a function is inserted upon **order** clause, seems that rails goes off-track in its query plan as the resulting SQL does not do the tables linkage and, therefore, issues the error:

```rb
> Subscription.includes(plan: { student: :person }).order('unaccent(persons.name)')
=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "persons")
LINE 1: ...subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" ORDER BY unaccent(persons.na...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" ORDER BY unaccent(persons.name) LIMIT $1
```

The same does not apply to **joins** that executes the command BUT using **INNER JOIN**s as the table linkage (not exactly the intended relationship)

```rb
> Subscription.joins(plan: { student: :person }).order('unaccent(persons.name)')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation ... > # GOOD
```

As a newbie here, what am I missing?

Comment: @TomLord `references`did the trick. `Subscription.includes(plan: { student: :person }).references(:person).order('unaccent(persons.name)')` got the desired output flawlessly. Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Re-written from my comment above)

You need to add `.references(:persons)` to the query.

Rails tries to be "lazy" and avoid performing unnecessary `JOIN`s when using `includes`. The usage of this `unaccent` SQL function is throwing off the ActiveRecord query planner - so you need to be more explicit, thus forcing rails to perform the JOIN.

See [the documentation on "conditions"](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes):

> If you want to add conditions to your included models you’ll have to
>   explicitly reference them. For example:
>
> `User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example')`
>
> Will throw an error, but this will work:
>
> `User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example').references(:posts)`
>
> Note that includes works with
>   association names while references needs the actual table name

Comment: Hi @TomLord ... just a follow up of the above discussion:

a) Seems that as per 4.2.7 forward, rails introduced the `eager_load` method that, besides `left_join` seems to be the preferred solution for issue:

`Subscription.left_join(plan: { student: :person }).order('unaccent(persons.name)')`

 OR

`Subscription.eager_load(plan: { student: :person }).order('unaccent(persons.name)')`

Comment: b) My misunderstand with the `includes` method is that it works with `.order('table.field')` but doesn't with `.order('function(table.field)')`. That's odd. I would settle if it doesn't work for neither :|

Anyway. Tks a lot.

Comment: a) There are plenty of other explanations online about the differences between these method, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53415106/1954610). In this instance, with no other context, all 3 method probably produce equivalent results.

Comment: b) The reason that it *"doesn't work"* is because rails has no knowledge of the SQL function, so fails to automatically understand that the JOIN is needed.