# Rails joins nested table with condition and prevents N+1 query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The models are simply `User` and `Review`. Relationship:  `User` has many `Reviews`. I want to query out which User has more than 2 reviews.

I wrote this and it works.

```
User.joins(:reviews).group(:id).having("COUNT('reviews.id') > 2")
```

Then I want to wrap them and return users' `id`, `first_name` and the review's `title`. Therefore, I've tried the following but throwing out an N+1 query issue.

```
User.select(:id,:first_name)
    .joins(:reviews).group(:id)
    .having("COUNT('reviews.id') > 2")
    .as_json(include: {reviews: {only: :title}})
```

Simply replace `joins` to `includes` seems not working, is there any way to solve eager loading with `group`, `having` condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.select(:id, :first_name).left_joins(: reviews).includes(: reviews).group(:id).having("COUNT('reviews.id') > 2")
```

It works for me, however, I do not what is `.as_json(include: {items: {only: :title}})` and if it will works with `.as_json(include: {items: {only: :title}})`

Comment: I'm sorry, it was the wrong model name. It's as_json(include: {`reviews`..}, not `items`

Comment: So basically, if I want to use eager loading with `joins`, I need to add `left_joins`? Can you explain why only `includes` doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @CodaChang I am not very familiar with SQL, in my understanding, joins using inner join, and in your case, left outer join would be better. You can use joins, but the query will be `User.select(:id, :first_name).joins(:reviews).includes(: reviews).group(:id).having("COUNT(*) > 2")`.  Only includes not working, in my understanding is you should use join when using having.

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53414830/whats-the-difference-between-left-joins-and-includes-in-rails-5